# Create Migration using command

Tags: laravel, model, command, migration

guys.

I tried creating a migration, model and controller using the php artisan commands and it was all created, but with wrong permissions: if I want to modify something and then save it in these new files, I need to save using sudo, which is a waste of time. I'd like to know if there's a way to change those permissions when creating the files. The docker is already outside sudo.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Run php artisan command with the user you will use to access this files later or change the permissions for the files after you create them.